# LaTeX: remove left margin of listing inside a table

Tags: latex, tabular, lstlisting

Using *LaTeX*, I need to show some code snippet inside a table.  Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
\begin{document}
Par exemple :
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lp{5cm}l}
\hline
Méthode & Description & Exemple d'utilisation\\
\hline
\texttt{isLetter()}& Indique si le caractère est une lettre de l'alphabet. &
\begin{lstlisting}[numbersep=0pt]
QChar MyChar('x');
bool IsLetter = MyChar.isLetter();
\end{lstlisting} \\
\hline
\texttt{toUpper()}& Retourne le même caractère mais en majuscules. & toto \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result I get :

[image]
.

As you can see, there is a margin on the left of the code. I guess this margin is there for numbering, but I don't need numbering and would like to get rid of it. I've tried changing some options (`numbersep`, `xleftmargin`) but none is working as I wish.

**UPDATE**

Here is the full document demonstrating the problem :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item Par exemple :
      \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{lp{5cm}l}
      \hline
      Méthode & Description & Exemple d'utilisation\\
      \hline
      \texttt{isLetter()}& Indique si le caractère est une lettre de l'alphabet. &
      \begin{lstlisting}[numbersep=0pt]
QChar MyChar('x');
bool IsLetter = MyChar.isLetter();
// IsLetter vaut vrai
QChar MyChar2('&');
IsLetter = MyChar2.isLetter();
// IsLetter vaut faux
      \end{lstlisting}\\
      \hline
      \texttt{toUpper()}& Retourne le même caractère mais en majuscules. & toto \\
      \end{tabular}
      \end{center}
   \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I can deduce that the problem is because the table is in a item of an enumeration.

Is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to reproduce your error. I've tested with the article-documentclass and the snippet you provided, but there wasn't any indent.

Anyway, you might try to write `\noindent\begin{lstlisting}` which avoids paragraph indentation (must be used at the beginning).

Comment: Same here, no indent. Can we see your preamble?

Comment: @tux21 and @Joseph Wright : I updated my question. My first code snippet didn't show my table was part of an item in an enumeration. This is the source of the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Image link is broken. Re-upload?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the margin is indeed coming from the enumeration. But luckily, the package documentation of the listing package notes:

> **resetmargins= true|false              (default: false)**
>
> If true, indention from list environments like enumerate or itemize
> is reset,  i.e. not used.

Therefore, the following should help:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[numbersep=0pt,resetmargins=true]
```

Regards,
Christoph

Comment: This didn't work for me using `lstset` for figures outside of a table (unlike in this question)

Answer (score 14):

The problem is caused by the table environment. By default latex inserts a small space in front of a row. This can be avoided by using the code `@{}` before the first column specification.

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}lp{5cm}l}
...
\end{tabular}
```

For more information about `@{}` see [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#.40-expressions).

Your full code example will then be

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item Par exemple :
      \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{@{}lp{5cm}l}
      \hline
      Méthode & Description & Exemple d'utilisation\\
      \hline
      \texttt{isLetter()}& Indique si le caractère est une lettre de l'alphabet. &
      \begin{lstlisting}[numbersep=0pt]
QChar MyChar('x');
bool IsLetter = MyChar.isLetter();
// IsLetter vaut vrai
QChar MyChar2('&');
IsLetter = MyChar2.isLetter();
// IsLetter vaut faux
      \end{lstlisting}\\
      \hline
      \texttt{toUpper()}& Retourne le même caractère mais en majuscules. & toto \\
      \end{tabular}
      \end{center}
   \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @midtiby : many thanks for the tip, I didn't know about `@{}`. It doesn't solve my actual problem though (but tux21b does). Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a negative left margin.

```
\begin{enumerate}[
        xleftmargin=-40pt %the 40pt may not apply depending on your environment
    ]
    % ... your enumeration here ...
\end{enumerate}
```

(I was using this for code snippet listings)